# TS2551: Property 'isCollapse' does not exist on type '{ collapse(): void; }' How to deal with it

Tags: vue.js

I encountered this error when writing a navigation bar shrink function, the function is actually fine, but it is a red error：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHXg0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPtjF.png)

I tried asking my classmates, but no one had a solution, and searching online didn't turn up any reference

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: also [Why should I not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6225326)?  Just going off the error message though, in "TS2551" the TS stands for typescript.  usually this type of error just means typescript isn't configured correctly.  How to fix it will depend on if you're using Vue 2 or Vue 3, and you'll need to show how you've currently configured TS with your app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.